# Microseconds in timestamp : db2 query

Tags: sql, db2, timestamp

I want microseconds in timestamp so I am using below query but not getting the microseconds

```
select TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.NNNNNN') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Getting : `2013-06-01 02:45:12`
Expected output:`2013-06-01 02:45:12.145235`

Ref:http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_bif_timestampformat.htm

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "not getting the microseconds"? You may also want to check the format specifier for minutes...

Comment: Given that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` _returns_ a timestamp, why do you feel you need `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(...)`?  Note that, depending on your dbtools settings, they may not be displayed (ie - some tools use 'region specific' date settings, which may give 2-digit years, instead of 4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you use wrong function, i.e. `timestamp_format` usage is:

> TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function returns a timestamp that is based on
>   interpreting the input string by using the specified format.

The functions receives **string** and returns **timestamp** - conversion is done following specification string. Example:

```
VALUES (TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('1999-12-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
--------------------------
1999-12-31-23.59.59.000000
```

Conversion tst to string could be done like this:

```
VALUES cast(current_timestamp as varchar(40))
----------------------------------------
2013-06-05-23.19.15.125000
```

Getting only microseconds could be done by using [microsecond](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_microsecond.htm) function like this:

```
VALUES( microsecond(current_timestamp), current_timestamp)
----------- --------------------------
     468000 2013-06-05-23.21.10.468000
```

Note: microsecond returns number, not string.

Answer (score 1):

use this piece of code to convert string datetime into timestamp format

```
 TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('2017-03-01 14:26:02.646171', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.NNNNNN')
```